# How to redistribute modified code under PSF license

Tags: licensing, python, open-source

I spent a few hours cleaning up a really old Python library, [ProxyTypes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ProxyTypes/0.9). Two days from now will mark 10 years since it was updated. Today, I updated it to support the newer Python 3, and to be compliant with the PEP8 style guide. I've stripped out some of the code I don't need, but the functionality and logic of the remaining code are unchanged.

I want to redistribute my modified version with a larger software project of mine, omitting all setup files and only including my modified version of the core file. **My project is MIT licensed**.

I've tried reading the PSF license text, but the license seems to talk specifically about redistribution of Python itself, and `ProxyTypes` is a 3rd-party module which is not distributed with Python, as far as I can tell, so I quickly became confused as to which parts of the PSF license actually apply to the code I'm trying to redistribute.

Additionally, it appears that the PSF license has changed dramatically over time. This code is 10 years old, should I assume that the PSF license means whatever version was current at the time of publication?

What attribution do I need to include my modified version of this file? Should I include my own copyright below any other necessary attribution to show that I've modified it, not merely redistributed it?

Comment: If it's a 3rd party library, did they also release it under the PSF license?  If that is the case, then re-interpret the license as if the library were Python.  Otherwise, you need to look at the license for the library specifically.

Comment: NOTE: the bottom of that page you linked to suggests sending direct queries to the PEAK mailing list: http://www.eby-sarna.com/mailman/listinfo/PEAK/ Is anyone still monitoring it?

Comment: Not sure. I'll try that.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch The email is dead. It's configured to no longer receive messages. The response is: "You are not allowed to post to this mailing list, and your message has been automatically rejected."

Comment: It's a shame, but after 10 years of inactivity it happens.  I downloaded the source to see if I could find any tell tale license information.  The PKG-INFO file lists these as the dual licenses: PSF or ZPL

Comment: @BerinLoritsch That means I can pick whichever I want, right? I'll look into ZPL

Comment: Only problem is that ZPL could be Zimbra Public License or Zope Public License.  Since Zope is Python related, I'm assuming that's what it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42674/discussion-between-berin-loritsch-and-luke-taylor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some legwork, downloading the last package that was available for the library the only licensing information I found was in the PKG-INFO file:

> License: PSF or ZPL

Which makes me believe you can choose either.  After 10 years of neglect, efforts to contact the author may not go well, but it's worth attempting any obvious action you can.  Based on our conversation, you were unsuccessful.

The [ZPL](https://opensource.org/licenses/ZPL-2.0) states the following restrictions:

1. Maintain the copyright notice
2. You cannot use Zope to endorse or promote your library or use their trademarks (branding restrictions)
3. And the more troublesome clause stating all changes must be prominently marked:

> If any files are modified, you must cause the modified
>      files to carry prominent notices stating that you changed
>      the files and the date of any change.

Considering the type of changes you made you may be able to address the concerns in the following manner:

- Header comments describing the systemic changes (Python 3 modernization, etc.)
- Comments above the specific method you had to re-implement

It is a common practice to keep a copy of the license you are using in a text file named `LICENSE` or `LICENSE.txt` if you want to be friendly to Windows users.  That makes it much clearer how you expect your library to be used.

Comment: I have a LICENSE file for the MIT license I'm using, do I need another one for ProxyTypes? It's not clear from your answer whether I need to include the whole license or just what it is. You say "the license you are using," which is MIT, and I've done that.

Comment: Yes, you want the LICENSE file for ProxyTypes.  If you are using it as a library, include it in the library source code.  If you are embedding it, then have a ProxyTypes.License file

Comment: Ok. My modified version is a separate file, so I can just include it in the source. Thanks

Comment: Should I try to find out what version was in use 10 years ago, or just use the latest?

Comment: I'd just use the latest.

Comment: Ok. I was about to give up on finding the dates on them, anyway.

Comment: Could you please review https://github.com/controversial/ui2/blob/cc69b11d2c41469d857e4f7e387e4e67e9dfb062/ui2/proxies.py to double-check what I did for me? The license mentions a credits file which I don't have, which gives me some concern... What do you think?

Comment: @LukeTaylor, I think you covered the changes properly, but the way it's described makes me think that if the original writer did find your copy and cared he might have cause to give you problems with the re-licensing.  ZPL is compatible with the MIT license, so there should be no issues with keeping the ZPL for this library.  While chances are low that this scenario will play out, it's best to play it safe just in case there is some white knight out there.

Comment: Hmm, does re-licensing have to be explicitly allowed? I don't see it forbidden. But you suggest that I make just that one file ZPL?

Comment: My knowledge of law is quite limited, but as long as you can't claim to be the 100% copyright owner, you can't change the terms of licensing code that someone else owns.  That would be like me deciding to change the terms on how Michael Jackson's "Beat It" just because I modernized the arrangement.  The lawyers would have a field day with me.  If you did a clean room re-engineering of the library, you could claim 100% copyright ownership and license it however you choose.  You can even change licensing terms between releases.  But only if you have 100% copyright ownership.

Comment: Ok @BerinLoritsch. So how exactly do I say this? I have to make my modifications ZPL as well? How do I write that in the comment?

Comment: @LukeTaylor, The convention is one license file for the library (include next to library source files or in central Licenses directory).  Keep your modification comments the same within the file.  The modifications are licensed under the same ZPL in accordance with the ZPL license.

Comment: Ok. So my modification comments go in the code, license goes separately. I can't put my name on the license anywhere, then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42806/discussion-between-berin-loritsch-and-luke-taylor).